# Getting started with Facebook SDK 7.9.4 in Unity

Tags: facebook

I'm having trouble getting started initialising the Facebook SDK in my project.

I downloaded the Unity 5.5 beta from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom

This beta includes Facebook SDK 7.9.4

So if I skip past the manual install and go to the initialise step on this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples

And I start with

```
using Facebook.Unity;
```

I get an error:

> the Facebook namespace cannot be found.

How do I get the namespace working so that I can begin using the SDK? I have been searching the web for help all morning and coming up empty. Every tutorial I have found is based off installing the old version sdk manually, but this conflicts with the latest version and only causes more errors.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE do you use? VS15?
Try to switch on MonoDevelop or Rider, this problem was solved for me. For some unknown reason the reference on Facebook.dll wasn't added to Visual Studio project.